# Neovim+texlab+Skim configuration

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex

Trying to make forward and inverse search work but I'm not sure how to modify my configs. I am currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/f3fora/nvim-texlabconfig) to try and make it work, but I am not sure where to put the lines that - they claim in their README - are specific for configuring Skim.

My current `texlabconfig.lua`

```
return {
    'f3fora/nvim-texlabconfig',
    config = function()
        require('texlabconfig').setup(config)
    end,
    -- ft = { 'tex', 'bib' }, -- Lazy-load on filetype
    build = 'go build'
    -- build = 'go build -o ~/.bin/' if e.g. ~/.bin/ is in $PATH
    }
```

Current lspconfig

```
return {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig"
}
```